# What does "stalker status" mean in chat applications?

Tags: iphone, android, xmpp, chat

I have created an XMPP chat application for Android and iPhone. While testing the app in jwchat.org, users who are created from iPhone devices are shown as '**stalker**', and Android usernames are shown as online / offline. What does '**stalker**' mean? Because of this, messages are sent and received from Android to iPhone, but iPhone devices' messages are not recieved by Android devices. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stalker" is an unfortunate term that is embedded in the user interface of your client, not a standard part of the protocol.  It likely refers to people who are in your roster as `type="from"`, which indicates that they are subscribed to your presence but you are not subscribed to their presence.  If you want to change this state, send them:

```
<presence type='subscribe' to='stalker@example.com'/>
```

Once they accept with:

```
<presence type='subscribed' to='you@example.com'/>
```

You should have each other in the `type="both"` state on one anothers' rosters.

Comment: thanks a lot, for clarifying.., whenever IPhone device receive subscribe message , in response sent a 'subscribed' message to that user, i tried between Jwchat and IPhone devices, but after sending 'subscribed' message I didn't get that user presence after I restated the app.., please suggest me if I had wrong any where.

Comment: When you receive a subscribe, you typically send back a subscribed to say "yes", and then send a subscribe back (if you haven't already), in order to see the other person's presence.  What you are aiming for is roster type "both".  Please read section 3 of RFC 6122: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6121#section-3

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a presence problem on the iPhone app -- that it is successfully logging in/authenticating to the xmpp server, but then failing to send an xmpp presence stanza.

Do you have any traces of the xmpp communication?